# Combine two DELETE-Statements in node-ibm_db

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, db2

I would like to delete all entries from several tables using node-ibm_db. When I try the following code, only the first table gets cleaned. I have also tried without the \n and with a space between the statements. Nothing seems to work. I have found that firing two select statements in one call is supported [(link to github)](https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/issues/238). Can anyone help me to make that work for two DELETE-Statements, too?

`connection.prepare("DELETE FROM xxx.someTable;\nDELETE FROM xxx.someOtherTable;")`
I execute the prepared statement with `executeNonQuery()`.

Comment: Why do you think you need to execute two statements with one API call?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not familiar with the node database library specifically, nearly all of these libraries only allow you to execute a single command at a time.  However, you should be able to do this by creating a compound SQL block.  Here is the pure SQL, which should work if you put it in your string:

```
begin
   delete from sometable;
   delete from othertable;
end
```